# добавить элемент на страницу

Tags: javascript

есть собственно таблица , после которой нужно добавлять такую же по клику на +.
я так понимаю для начала нужно клонировать уже существующую и добавить ее в конец существующей. Подумал в начале, что как-то так должно быть, но что-то упускаю

вот сама таблица

```
<table class="personal_data" id="hidden_change_personal_data">
    <caption id="contact_list">Edit personal data</caption>                    
    <tr>
        <td class="personal_area_block1">                    
           <div class="contact_block_title">country</div>
        </td>
        <td class="personal_area_block2">
            <input type="text" name="new_name" id="new_data" class="contact_block_info" value="" />
        </td>                         
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="personal_area_block1">        
            <div class="contact_block_title"> city</div>
        </td>
        <td class="personal_area_block2" >                                   
            <input type="text" name="new_name" id="new_data" class="contact_block_info" value="" />
        </td>                   
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- нужно вставить сюда -->

<table class="personal_data" id="add_address_table">  
   <tr>                    
       <td class="personal_area_block1">                    
           <div class="contact_block_title">Add the address</div>
       </td>
       <td class="personal_area_block2">
            <img src="plus.png" class="contact_block_info" id="add_address" />
       </td>                         
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var changeD = document.getElementById('hidden_change_personal_data');
var addAddress = document.getElementById('add_address_table');
addAddress.addEventListener('click',function(){        
    var copy = changeD.cloneNode(true);
    copy.insertBefore(copy,changeD);
},false)
```

Comment: html разметку тоже добавьте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что вам нужен некий элемент, который бы содержал в себе таблицу, т.е. html должен быть типа такого:

```
<div id="parent">
    <table class="personal_data" id="hidden_change_personal_data">
        <caption id="contact_list">Edit personal data</caption>                    
        <tr>
            <td class="personal_area_block1">                    
               <div class="contact_block_title">country</div>
            </td>
            <td class="personal_area_block2">
                <input type="text" name="new_name" id="new_data" class="contact_block_info" value="" />
            </td>                         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="personal_area_block1">        
                <div class="contact_block_title"> city</div>
            </td>
            <td class="personal_area_block2" >                                   
                <input type="text" name="new_name" id="new_data" class="contact_block_info" value="" />
            </td>                   
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- нужно вставить сюда -->

<table class="personal_data" id="add_address_table">  
   <tr>                    
       <td class="personal_area_block1">                    
           <div class="contact_block_title">Add the address</div>
       </td>
       <td class="personal_area_block2">
            <img src="plus.png" class="contact_block_info" id="add_address" />
       </td>                         
   </tr>
</table>
```

И для такого html нужен такой JS:

```
var changeD = document.getElementById('hidden_change_personal_data');
var addAddress = document.getElementById('add_address_table');
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
addAddress.addEventListener('click',function(){        
    var copy = changeD.cloneNode(true);
    parent.insertBefore(copy,changeD.nextSibling);
},false)
```

Тогда будет добавляться всегда после первой таблицы.

Comment: так и подумал что тут проблема в отсутствии контейнера таблицы 
спасибо Вам за ответ - заработало